# What is the measure unit of Graphics2D or the 2D Components?

Tags: java, embedded, 2d, line, graphics2d

I'm working on a code that should allow me to draw an AC "Animated electricity" signal, and the time interval should be accurate in this case.
My question is; What is the measuring unit of the Point2D specifically, Is't pixels, milliseconds, or any unit else?
I'm trying to draw a Line2D, which should be drawn between two points!
I'd tried to take the '1' value as milliseconds and it's kind of worked, later on I discovered that the graphics elements is measured by pixels, I tried to convert millisecond to pixels with multiplying by pixel value, but it didn't give me the expected results.
My code as following expecting '1' value is Millie

```
<i>
for(i=0;i<20000;i++)
            {
                //System.out.println(volts[i]);

                if(i!=0)
                    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(time-(timeScale/y),-(((voltScale/x)*50*volts[i-1])-300),time,-(((voltScale/x)*50*volts[i])-300)));
                time+=(timeScale/y);
            }
</i>
```

Comment: In my case now I assume that timeScale/y =1, so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graphics2D class description gives a fairly good description of the units (in the "Coordinate Spaces" section:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Generally speaking, a unit in "User Space" (the Java2D coordinate system) will correspond to 1/72 inch on physical devices (such as your monitor or your printer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, sense no one answered, I think in the Graphics2D object case, It won't take it as pixels, maybe the pixels can't be cut into fractions, and Graphics2D is able to use fractions. Unfortunately seems like that the developers whose worked on the Graphics2D class doesn't give any clear description about it.